# Should I translate license to app's language?

Tags: mit

I'm developing a totally Persian portable (single .exe) app and want to apply [MIT license](https://choosealicense.com/licenses/mit/) on it. I included English license text in the help PDF which is embedded in app.
Should I translate license text to Persian also or only including English text is enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should **not** translate a license text yourself (or ask a non-lawyer to translate it). If there are multiple official translations of a license, then you can choose the one in a language spoken by the largest portion of your users, but I am not aware of any official translations of the MIT license.

A license is a legal document and if you try to translate that to a different language it is very likely that nuances get lost or added in the translation and that the translated license says something other than the original license, which effectively results in different licenses.

Apart from that, the license text is itself also protected by copyright and most authors of license texts don't give permission to make derived works (and a translation to a different human language is a prime example of a derived work) or you get that permission only on condition that you call the license differently.